# Reporting tool for ios (iphone ipad)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, crystal-reports, monodevelop

I'm planning to generate sharepoint report for iphone/ipad is there any crystal reports type reporting tool available for ios (iphone/ipad) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there are reporting tools for iOS, but I'd consider these options:

1. Prepare the report on a server and present it in an imageview or web view.
2. Find a JavaScript reporting library and present the report in a web view. I know you can pass the data to the web view. I think the way to do it is by passing the web view some additional JavaScript to process.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a framework to make PDF Reports on iOS devices. Actually I'm working on updating it with new features.

If you're interested it is downloadable from this link: https://github.com/htsoft/RSReport

You can find other informations here: http://www.htmedia.it

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this problem Salman.
Another solution to Noa's one may be to use charts libraries for iOS as CorePlot for example, and pass the charts/graphs to some UIView. You can then easily export it as PNG or PDF.

But in my case, it's not satisfying and I'm looking for real embedded reports solutions...

Comment: Note that Core Plot graphs have native methods for export to PNG or PDF.  There is no need to add them to another view in order to obtain an image of their contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a powerful reporting engine, you most likely will need to call a server as suggested by *noa* to do the complex work.  Alternatively you can create PDFs by code using iOS libraries and write the report-logic yourself.  Another option is to call a web service (like [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com)) that can generate and deliver documents without having to code the report layout.